Typeorm How to save data with @OneToOne relation?
I have two entity
ProductKey Entity
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Products } from './entity.products';

@Entity()
export class ProductKey {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public_key: string;

  @Column()
  private_key: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Products, (product) => product.product_key)
  product: Products;
}

Products Entity
@Entity()
@Unique(['no'])
export class Products {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  no!: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50, unique: true })
  @ApiProperty({ example: '0000203A3', description: 'unique ID' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  id!: string;

  // (1:1)
  @OneToOne(() => ProductKey, (productKey) => productKey.product, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'productKeyPublicKey',
    referencedColumnName: 'public_key',
  })
  product_key!: ProductKey;
}

I hope that when product information is generated, product key information is also generated at the same time. so I tried the code below
  const productKey = this.productKeyRepository.create({
    public_key: publicKeyPem,
    private_key: privateKeyPem,
  });

  const { sizes, materials, ...productData } = data; //variable data is dto
  const product = this.productRepository.create({
    ...productData,
    brand,
  });

  product.sizes = sizes.map((sizeDto) => {
    const productSize = this.productSizeRepository.create(sizeDto);
    productSize.product = product;
    return productSize;
  });

  product.material_content = materials.map((materialDto) => {
    const productMaterial =
      this.productMaterialRespository.create(materialDto);
    productMaterial.product = product;
    return productMaterial;
  });

  product.product_key = productKey;

  await this.productRepository.save(product);

But if I try the code, the error occurs.
[-ERROR] CREATE product error QueryFailedError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
key constraint fails (careid.products, CONSTRAINT FK_145ab0f179ff0d81bad6df1b428 FOREIGN
KEY (productKeyPublicKey) REFERENCES product_key (public_key) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
UPDATE CASCADE)
the error occurs with productKey can't still solve this problem..

Problem:
You are encountering the following error when trying to save a Products entity that references a ProductKey entity:
QueryFailedError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (careid.products, CONSTRAINT FK_145ab0f179ff0d81bad6df1b428 FOREIGN KEY (productKeyPublicKey) REFERENCES product_key (public_key) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Explanation:
The error indicates that the foreign key constraint on productKeyPublicKey in the products table is being violated because the public_key value in the product_key table does not exist or is not properly referenced.
Solution:
// Create and save the ProductKey first
const productKey = this.productKeyRepository.create({
  public_key: publicKeyPem,
  private_key: privateKeyPem,
});
await this.productKeyRepository.save(productKey); // Ensure it is saved to the database

// Extract product data
const { sizes, materials, ...productData } = data; // variable data is dto

// Create the Products entity
const product = this.productRepository.create({
  ...productData,
  brand,
  product_key: productKey, // Assign the saved ProductKey
});

// Add sizes and materials to the product
product.sizes = sizes.map((sizeDto) => {
  const productSize = this.productSizeRepository.create(sizeDto);
  productSize.product = product;
  return productSize;
});

product.material_content = materials.map((materialDto) => {
  const productMaterial = this.productMaterialRespository.create(materialDto);
  productMaterial.product = product;
  return productMaterial;
});

// Save the Products entity
await this.productRepository.save(product);

